# Java library to extract video format metadata

Tags: java, audio, video, metadata, extract

I want to know if StackOverflowers are aware of any Java library that can do metadata extractions (bit rate, aspect ratio, audio bit rate, etc....) for multiple video formats (mp4, flv, webm, ogg, etc.....). The more the better (as many metadata attributes, as well as many data formats). Thanks.

Comment: Have you even tried Google?

Comment: I wasn't able to find one yet